# Control bluetooth volume on phone?

Tags: bluetooth, volume-control

Seems like the volume control button on my bluetooth headset is broken, is there any way to change the bluetooth volume directly on the phone? I am on Android 4.1.2, just in case it's relevant. I found settings to change the normal front speaker volume, but nothing for the bluetooth volume.

Comment: Is that headset mono (for phone calls only) or stereo (also supports playing music)?

Comment: You can have a look at this if you are interested in trying a different approach, see my answer here [How do I disable the google voice typing/voice search 'ding' sound?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/128588/how-do-i-disable-the-google-voice-typing-voice-search-ding-sound/129241#129241)

Answer (score 0):

See if this helps. I am not sure though:

> Settings >> Sound >> Volumes

If this doesn't help try this [Bluetooth Volume app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nightshadelabs.bluetoothvolume&hl=en). This should do it.

Comment: Unfortunately no BT options in the mentioned menu ):

Comment: Does changing media volume there helps?

Comment: Thanks, but no it does not help, it also doesn't change to a lower volume when BT volume is changed during e.g. a SIP call. I noted that on a normal call I can change the bluetooth volume using the buttons on the phone, that's how I got maximum BT volume back. problem for the moment is, that I have to make a normal call to increase my BT volume, annoying :D