# How do I disable the google voice typing/voice search 'ding' sound?

Tags: google-voice-actions

Whenever I open google voice typing, it plays a rising ding sound, then a falling ding sound when it stops.

This is very annoying to me. I have a rooted stock S5 on Lollipop. I searched for the sound file but couldn't locate it, it may be wrapped up in the apk file.

Is there a way to stop this irritating sound? If I install the Xposed Framework, will that help?

Edit: Someone has suggested turning the media volume down to zero. This will work, but is not appropriate for me, as I am using the language learning app duolingo while I am using voice typing. So I need the app to send out audio via the media channel, simultaneously with using voice typing. Coming at it from another angle, [I have asked if there is an alternative application which meets my requirements.](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/26522/offline-voice-typing-alternative-for-android)

**edit**

**Using app settings 1.15, you can mute voice typing by muting the Google app in Marshmallow (and maybe above). However, voice typing now mutes other audio ( regardless of its configuration on app settings) so I asked a question about it here**

[How do I stop voice typing from muting/pausing other playing media?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/193881/how-do-i-stop-voice-typing-from-muting-pausing-other-playing-media)

Comment: Can you try silencing media volume for your device when you are voice typing? That should stop the sound, but not without side effects.

Comment: This can also be automated using Tasker or MacroDroid, or similar apps. On a side note, maybe Google Voice Typing has some relevant settings?

Comment: good point about media volume, but not an option for me unfortunately, see edit. Google Voice typing, as I said, doesn't have an option to disable this sound.

Comment: I found the audio file in the apk under res > raw and it is called open_mp3.mp3 if you still want to attempt that method.

Comment: That sounds perfect! But where is that folder? Can't see it in the explorer. I have root explorer

Comment: @HaydenMoulds Wouldn't that cause Google Play to not update that app whenever Google ships an update to it in Play Store?

Comment: It could yes. It is not in a folder, it is in the apk. If you use an app such as APKEditor or similar you will be able to see the files in the apk, and the internal folder structure. In that structure the sound file is there. But like Firelord pointed out this could cause a multitude of issues that come with editing APKs. Just pointing out that it is there and that is what it's called.

Comment: I have a solution  that will shut up all sounds coming from Google search (any sound from Google search app will not play like the talk back on Google now and stuff other apps can still make sound only Google search will shut up ) if that suits you I will post an answer

Comment: Yes, definitely!

Comment: Saw your pending edit; there seems to be higher versions of App Settings (I've personally used 1.15 on Nougat), though I'm not sure if those would work in terms of the specific feature you're looking for.

Comment: That works, thanks. Missed it as not in the official channel. I have another problem though: voice typing seems to pause playback of all other audio... Not what i want, and not sure how to solve it. I'll maybe post a question later.

Comment: Here we go https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/193881/how-do-i-stop-voice-typing-from-muting-pausing-other-playing-media

Comment: Btw you can go ahead and reject the edit. I don't think the new problem has to do with App Settings

Comment: I'm struggling with the same problem 6 years later - any updates? Especially ones that don't require a rooted phone? (Or should I just start a new question?)

Comment: Perhaps better to ask a new question at this point, workarounds often stop working when upgrades happen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a solution that may be useful ,if not for the OP I hope it will be useful as a reference for shutting the volume of a particular application OFF.

This method will mute all sounds coming from Google App but will not affect the other apps. It works on 4.1 up to Lollipop, but the questioner found that the App Settings Xposed module doesn't work on Marshmallow.

**Requirements :**

- Root access
- Xposed installer [Lollipop/Marshmallow](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=3034811) / [kitkat and older](http://forum.xda-developers.com/xposed/xposed-installer-versions-changelog-t2714053) / [Stock lollipop Samsung Only](http://forum.xda-developers.com/xposed/unofficial-xposed-samsung-lollipop-t3113463)  (!)
- App settings xposed Module get it from [here](http://repo.xposed.info/module/de.robv.android.xposed.mods.appsettings) (install apk on phone )

**Method :**

- make sure app settings is activated in `xposed installer` under "**modules**" reboot after activating for the first time.
- now open App settings and type `Google` in the search field.
- You will see in the list the `Google App` click on it.
- on the Activity Bar you will see a toggle button toggle it `ON`.
- A view with lots of settings will show up ,look at the bottom of the screen just above the permission  button there is a check box that say "**Mute audio**" check it.
- now click on the save button in the right side of the activity bar and confirm the pop-up message.
- Now open the voice typing and enjoy the full silence :)

> (!) For Samsung devices under Lollipop Follow carefully the thread you must have a deodexed Rom.

Comment: Will give this one a whack as it targets the problems precisely. Unfortunately xposed don't work on stock lollipop touchwiz. I will install it at some point as I need it for other stuff. Sadly that means installing a whole new Rom and losing all my apps :/

Comment: @Ne Mo is your touchwiz rom deodexed ? If so xposed exists for your rom

Comment: No, it's not sadly. And if I understand correctly that means I'll need to install a new Rom if I want xposed

Comment: @NeMo yes you gonna have to install a new deodexed rom ,you can deodex and keep your apps if you deodex the same Rom that you are running now

Comment: At the moment I've got 5.0, are you saying if I install any 5.0 tw deodexed rom, I'll keep the apps?

Comment: No ,I am saying that you can backup the system partition via TWRP ,extract it ,deodex the apps ,flash it back and you can keep every thing since it's the same Rom that way you can limit the chances of any unexpected behavior

Comment: I got round to installing xposed, and this works beautifully, thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Automation is my solution.

There are plenty of automation apps, but I use [MacroDroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.arlosoft.macrodroid), since it is easy to learn (that's why I use it) and the behaviour can be easily customized to get the result you want. Besides,free version allows you to create up to 5 macros and so for the task at hand, free version suffices. I prefer automation as a first choice when I need to get something running the way I want rather than depend on an app.

MacroDroid uses macros to perform desired actions.

Macro for your requirement would look like this:

(I am **thankful to OP for testing** o on his Lollipop based device and confirming behaviour as expected, since my device runs on KitKat and Google has implemented API level changes differently in Lollipop)

#### Main Macro (working as tested by OP)

#### Trigger

Application Launched → Google

#### Action

Volume Change → Configure

Here you get 7 options which can be chosen singly or in combination on a sliding scale from 0 to 100. Options are-
 1. Alarm
 2. Music
 3. Notifications
 4. Ringer
 5. System Sounds
 6. Voice Call
 7. Bluetooth Voice

Choose ((2) Music and (5) System Sounds) and set them to 0 for **Lollipop**

Choose ((3) Notifications and (5) System Sounds) and set them to 0 for **KitKat**

( Reason for different selection is explained in Note below)

You can set the (6) Voice call level as desired ( select by testing  voice
typing comfort level)

#### Constraints

None

(Macro runs only when constraint is *true*, so here it runs always)

Save the macro and ensure it is enabled   before testing

#### Optional Macro (Awaiting OP to test)

(In case you need to change volume manually for voice typing, the "ding sound reappears, as reported by OP. This macro is to kill the "ding sound". This macro is not required if you are fine with the voice control level in the main macro and do not need to manually change voice typing volume)

#### Trigger

Volume Button Pressed → Volume Up  →  Update Volume

(Followed by)

Volume Button Pressed → Volume Down  →  Update Volume

#### Action and Constraints

Same as in the main macro

( Triggers work as logical *OR* and the action for muting the "ding sound" is triggered whenever the volume is manually increased or decreased for voice typing )

#### Why this should work for everybody

1. My search hasn't shown an app or Xposed module that can do this ( not denying the possibility, though)
2. This macro **doesn't require root** unlike Xposed approach.
3. **Granular control on different Volume settings**. MacroDroid permits you to alter sounds, with a flexibility that is beyond what normally is available in ringer / volume sound control as this example illustrates. My Huawei Honor 6 has only 6 types of volume settings (which is more than some devices offer) but not Bluetooth, which can be controlled through a macro
4. **Customization**. You can set "modes", which are like global variables akin to setting profiles. As an example, you can set this macro to run while at home (by mapping cell towers of your home location) and have the "ding" sound active elsewhere. Possibilities for customization are pretty much as you wish
5. Last but not least, **it is free :-)**

#### System Settings

1. Do not Greenify MacroDroid and exclude it from task killers, if you use them.
2. Enable MacroDroid in "Auto Protect"(Huawei phones) or "Stamina Mode" (Sony phones or "Power Nap" (Stamina Mode Xposed module for non Sony devices). Also, if you update to Marshmallow in the future, exclude MacroDroid from Doze. Refer this: [Is there a way to exclude an app from Doze?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/129074/is-there-a-way-to-exclude-an-app-from-doze/129075)

These features prevent app(s) to be active when the device is not awake, conserving battery. May not be pertinent to your phone but adding this as a general precaution.

3. Enable MacroDroid in accessibility settings and also allow it as device administrator in security settings.
4. For Lollipop, enable notification access from notification settings

#### Note

Google Voice Recognition functionality that creates the "ding" sound  was streamed as notification stream  in KitKat. In Lollipop this is switched to music  stream. Hence, in the macro, settings differ.

**Source**: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21701432/continues-speech-recognition-beep-sound-after-google-search-update

Comment: +1 for being thorough with this. I might have come up with a Tasker solution, but since yours does the job admirably, probably it isn't necessary anymore.

Comment: Your logic was impeccable, but... it plum ain't workin'. See edit

Comment: Still doesn't work quite right. It works the first time, but then when I manually increase the volume again and press voice typing, the sound is back. Even if you hide the keyboard then bring it back again. Very odd. Does that happen for you? I expect the google process is still running in the background. Also it is definitely the music/ media slider which controls the ding

Comment: @NeMo. Out of curiosity, did this solution finally work or not?  Not relating it to bounty

Comment: I felt bad about not awarding it to you, but I preferred his solution as it did not entail muting the media volume for all apps.

Comment: @NeMo. That's fine and am perfectly fine that. What I need to know from a learning point, is does the solution work or not

Comment: I didn't get around to changing the macro on volume button press. I'll get around to it and let you know

Comment: Thanks and  just as FYI, " not muting audio for all apps", was a concern I anticipated and was asked in the earlier solution (current solution was competent revised to give it a final look ) ads can be achieved by simply adding the app as constraint

Comment: Located earlier reply which had this" From your description of the requirements, it appears that more tweaking may be required in terms of when you want this macro to run, for instance do you want this macro to be always run or in conjunction with some app(s) only? ...". There was no revert on this aspect and I naturally assumed that this is not a concern for you. Just setting record.straight. in constraint add application running> running in foreground>[app name from list] and macro only triggers when this is app running