# Force Skype and Hangouts to keep running

Tags: task-management, processes

Skype and Hangouts automatically kill themselves after a period of inactivity if it's not in the foreground. As I want to appear online and receive IMs/calls, this is an incredible inconvenience.

Is there anything like process manager or similar that forces apps to keep running and/or lock app activity state?

**NOTE** Since my phone has a GB of RAM and only uses just a bit less than half with all regular apps open, it's not an Android memory management issue.

Comment: Automation solution posted by me here http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/128732/how-to-make-skype-always-active-reliably-receiving-and-notifying-about-calls-in