# Skype doesn't receive calls unless the app is open and in the foreground

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, skype, motorola-moto-e

This is on a Moto E running Android 4.4.4.
Skype doesn't seem to receive calls or messages unless the app is open. If the app is not open, then no notification happens.

Comment: Are you using a battery saver app, such as Greenify?

Comment: No. No battery saver app.

Comment: This has been an issue with Skype for Android for about as long as I can remember, honestly.  Their forums have quite a lot of posts related to it. [This question](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/128732/981) has an answer that basically attempts to bring Skype back to the foreground constantly, but I can't vouch for its effectiveness. I personally gave up because I could never get Skype to behave properly.

Comment: Weird.  Skype on my android seems to be always running as a service and logged in.  When I get the occassional message, I'm always surprised when it shows up on my desktop (which I intentionally log in) and my phone (which I always forget is connecting)