# Default rotation direction for landscape apps

Tags: auto-rotation

My device is Samsung Galaxy S5 with Android lollipop.

Some games run on a landscape mode and the top-side becomes left-hand side and bottom becomes right-hand side.
Can I change this so that top goes right and bottom goes left?
I don't want to rotate my phone every single time I run these apps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily achieve this by automation. I prefer [MacroDroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.arlosoft.macrodroid) Being easy to learn and free

To understand how MacroDroid works and the settings required for your Android version, see  my [answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/130619/remote-manage-the-wifi-connection)

Your macro would look like this and you can tweak as you like

**Trigger**: *Application Launched / Closed* → Select your application

**Action**:  *Force Screen Rotation* →*Force Landscape* (or) *Force Landscape 180* (Screen shot below shows possible options)

**Constraints**: None

[image]