# Disable homescreen auto rotation on rooted stock Xperia Z2?

Tags: home-screen, xposed-framework, auto-rotation, sony-xperia-z2

My rooted Xperia Z2 has the latest stock firmware(23.4.A.1.232) and the Xposed framework. I don't know how or where, but now the homescreen also rotates when tilting the phone and I've not found any setting to change it. I have tried Xblast tools from the Xposed repository, it has an option to change home screen rotation, but that doesn't work either.

Can this be fixed?

Comment: Do you want to stop rotation always or for some apps? Have a look at this and let me know if you want changes http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/132945/default-rotation-direction-for-landscape-apps

Comment: Not for any apps. Just the home screen. I already have Tasker to turn it off for specific apps.

Comment: Trigger: Screen unlocked . Action: auto rotate off should do the trick.Please check and see this for MacroDroid set up and q quick start http://android.stackexchange.com/a/133394/131553

Comment: Please let me know if it works for you and will post as answer

Comment: You can setup default orientation using [App Settings](http://repo.xposed.info/module/de.robv.android.xposed.mods.appsettings) module. I think [Rotation - Orientation Manager](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.pranavpandey.rotation&hl=en) would also work for per app orientation setting. Your ROM is not close to stock Android so I'll hold back from posting an answer until you confirm the success.