# Need to invert Accelerometer Axis

Tags: tablet, sensors, android-x86

I need a way to flip the x-axis of my accelerometer (When the value would be positive, I want to make the output negative, and vice-versa). Currently, if I tilt the tablet into portrait mode (or reverse portrait) the screen is upside-down. The y-axis is fine. I don't mind editing an orientation app if I have to.

Comment: Are you running a custom rom? If so, you may have installed a rom for a slightly different product line than yours (ex. international model rom on a US variant).

Comment: As i understand you want to your the axis because of display issues on changing portrait to landscape. If that is the case, you can try solution on lines suggested here http://android.stackexchange.com/a/132948/131553

Comment: Are you using any 3 party library.

Comment: 1.) I'm using android-x86 on a convertible tablet/laptop. 2.) It's not just for orientation, that's just an example. If I were to play a game with tilt controls I would mimic Disney and "turn right to go left". I already use one of those orientation apps, I want to make it a more complete fix.