# Screen rotation lock won't work for landscape mode

Tags: samsung, 7.0-nougat, samsung-touchwiz, samsung-galaxy-s7

For some reason, when I put the phone in landscape mode and enable the rotation lock, it just sets the screen to portrait mode and then locks the rotation. I want to be able to keep the screen in landscape mode, is there a way to do this? I am using a Samsung Galaxy S7, with Android Nougat and the TouchWiz launcher. I am happy to switch to Google Now Launcher if it lets me lock the screen in landscape though.

Comment: You can try the solution [here](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/132945/131553) if it is for a specific app(s) or try this Trigger: screen on; Action: force screen rotation> force landscape; constraints: Device orientation> landscape

Comment: The second option requires some tweaking.. Let me know if you are interested in this approach

Comment: grrr this happens with stock Android on a non-Samsung phone as well!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modified from one of my previous answers:

> Use apps like [Ultimate Rotation Control](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=nl.fameit.rotate) - with proper settings, it seamlessly integrates with system rotation toggle, and on top of that you can enable/disable any rotation direction, force apps that don't usually rotate to rotate, and set per-app rotation behavior.