# How to allow rotating upside down in portait mode

Tags: screen, auto-rotation

I have HTC 10, Android 7.0. When I charge it, I have the display upside down in portrait mode. I.e. the button is further from me. The screen doesn't rotate by "gravity" so I see everything upside down.

Is there a way to make the phone screen rotate so that the notification bar would be at the actual bottom of the display?

*Update:* I've tried a Set Orientation app. That works for the above, but causes problems with apps, like, camera app can't layout correctly.

Comment: You can try the solution [here](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/132945/131553) with Trigger being  *Power Connected*.

Comment: That's a good trick if I always had it like that, but sometimes I take the phone to hand and then I need it in the default orientation again...

Comment: `settings put system user_rotation x` where x is a number between 0 and 3