# Android's screen is rotated by 90 degrees

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, adb, screen, samsung-galaxy-s-5

So I saw this command:

adb shell wm size 1080x1920

and I wanted to try it, so I did but my screen is now flipped, and I can't even take a screen shot because it says "Prevented by security policy".
 I have tried already to run some screen rotating commands like this: adb shell settings put system user_rotation 3 , and similar commands but nothing works.

I have a Galaxy S5 not rooted and I don't want to factory reset it or root it. It boots fine (the Android and Samsung logos) but the home screen and apps are just rotated 90 degrees.

Comment: You can try the solution [here](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/132945/131553). Change the Trigger to Device Boot

Comment: Are you just looking to turn it back to what it was? `adb shell wm size reset`

Comment: I'm making this a proper answer just in case...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're just looking to turn it back to what it was, use the command `adb shell wm size reset`.