# How to set which landscape mode is default (reverse landscape vs landscape)

Tags: auto-rotation

I have a few different apps that seem to have difficulties keeping landscape mode from going upside down when certain things happen, like playing ads. My phone is always rotated clockwise for landscape mode when I use landscape mode, but will often go upside down as if it expects the phone to be rotated counter-clockwise. I'm assuming rotated counter-clockwise is considered landscape mode, and clockwise is reverse landscape, so in that case I need reverse landscape to be the main/default/only landscape mode. But I don't want it locked to landscape all the time, it is locked to portrait mode normally. Using Galaxy S8+, not rooted.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions/advice, though preferably not something that requires changing a setting before and after every time I launch one of those troublesome apps.

Comment: Can you accept an app that will change portrait/landscape on a click (in the notification dropdown)? It will only switch between rotation directions/modes you desire.

Comment: Related  https://android.stackexchange.com/q/132945/131553

Comment: @AndyYan If it works, I could live with it lol

Comment: @beeshyams Having trouble with macrodroid, it works really well for one of the apps, but completely breaks tap detection for another one in the same way that a facebook messenger head does (which normally doesn't appear when playing)

Comment: There is an app called control screen orientation... it works great. You can find it on the play store

Answer (score 1):

Quoted from one of my previous answers:

> Use apps like [Ultimate Rotation Control](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=nl.fameit.rotate) - with proper settings, it seamlessly integrates with system rotation toggle, and on top of that you can enable/disable any rotation direction, force apps that don't usually rotate to rotate, and set per-app rotation behavior.

Based on your description, set the first options to these values so you can click the app's notification to toggle rotation direction.

[image]

Do note that this is a paid app with a 7-day trial.

Comment: That works well for a simple notification bar option to change rotations, but the per app settings did not work. However, from that found another one [Rotation Control](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jp.snowlife01.android.rotationcontrol&hl=en) that the per app settings do work flawlessly with my apps, although I lose the easy navigation bar change. Thanks for the suggestion :)

Comment: You should probably write an answer yourself containing that app you thought worked better, for others' future reference and for sweet karma :)

Answer (score 0):

Found an app [Rotation Control](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jp.snowlife01.android.rotationcontrol&hl=en) that lets you easily set up per app settings to be any direction you want, so no need for another notification bar icon/entry making clutter up there. Works with all the apps I've been able to test with, really easy to set up and see what apps you have set up. It is a paid app with a 2 day trial, but the ones that worked with my apps seemed to be paid apps anyways. This one was the easiest to use/setup.