# Decrease default vibration length on notification?

Tags: notifications, vibration

Is there any way to decrease the duration of vibration on receiving a notification? I want to keep it short, like you can do it for WhatsApp messages.

I'm running 5.1 on Moto G 1st gen, not currently rooted.

Comment: Check under settings/sounds and notification/vibration pattern. Or vibration intensity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Automation is the preferred option. Many apps are available. I prefer using [MacroDroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.arlosoft.macrodroid) , since it is free (upto 5 macros) and easy to learn. To understand how MacroDroid works and the **settings** required for your Android version, see  my [answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/130619/remote-manage-the-wifi-connection)

**Note**  This is not tested on Lollipop  as I am on KitKat but should work. Ensure appropriate settings for lollipop are made

Your macro would look like this

**Trigger**:

*Incoming Notification* → *From* →*choose Application* (in addition to application you can customise depending on the text content of notification)

**Action**:

- *Vibrate* →*Short buzz* (*Ten other variations possible like Rapid, slow, increasing, decreasing etc*)

**Constraints**: *None*

**Edit:**  For more details and explanation on MacroDroid, please see my answer here [How to prevent brightness from going to full when the battery low popup appears?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/120088/how-to-prevent-brightness-from-going-to-full-when-the-battery-low-popup-appears)

Comment: I'll check this out

Comment: I have made a macro, and I'm testing it. I've made one to vibrate when notification receive (short vibrate), in the case of not being on silent mode. Is that correct? Will this prevent the sound from playing too? I haven't yet tested completely

Comment: I am not able to understand . Other actions that can help are *vibrate enable/disable and volume change*. If you have more than one action, it helps if you add *wait before next action to 10 seconds,* in between actions. You can reduce later after testing but from my experience less than 5 seconds doesn't always work

Comment: I've done what you've said in your answer, except I've added a constraint that the phone should be on non-silent mode. And I sent myself a couple of messages just now and it seems to be working properly 

Comment: Good. Enjoy playing around. See the templates section of the app to get an idea of what you can do and also explore the forum (both available from main interface of app). Do consider "accepting" answer, and upvote,this would help others also decide the value of answer. Your choice, of course