# How can I change the vibrate duration for Google Calendar app reminder notifications?

Tags: notifications, nexus-5, calendar, google-calendar, vibration

I have a Nexus 5 running Android 6.0.1.  I have vibration enabled, and when a Calendar reminder notification triggers, my phone vibrates twice, quickly.

This is often too fast/too weak for me to notice when my phone is in my pocket, so I'd like to increase it somehow.  How could I do that?

Comment: This may interest you, if you find that there is no native way to achieve what you want: [Decrease default vibration length on notification?](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/133214) (other [tag:automation] apps would do the job as well)

Comment: Solution here for a very similar requirement worked on Lollipop http://android.stackexchange.com/a/133214/131553. You can try it out on your device . For quick start, settings etc see http://android.stackexchange.com/a/133394/131553. Ensure you implement settings and revert do that it can be posted as an answer. Hesitant to post as I can't test on Marshmallow