# Nexus 5X vibrates despite disabling in app settings

Tags: nexus-5, nexus-5x, project-fi

My phone vibrates on all notifications despite turning off vibrate in the settings of each individual app that has the option. How can I block vibrating notifications for specific apps?

According to the Google support page and forums there is no way to disable vibrate globally without entering do-not-disturb mode, but it should work on an app by app basis. Turning it off within an app changes the vibration and they now all act the same. So it seems like the option is disabling the vibration that comes from the app but there is some system wide notification that always happens.

The phone is a new Nexus 5X that I just received after signing up with Project Fi. The phone vibrations are extremely grating and can't be changed or lowered. Not being able to limit them without putting the phone in DND mode is driving me nuts. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: It works! I had not known about MacroDroid. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is similar to the question here [Decrease default vibration length on notification?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/133209/131553)

Tweak that solution with following changes

1. Trigger - Notification received from all apps
2. Action-Volume change> system sounds slider value to zero