# How to make sure Android'a notification can give sound and vibrate?

Tags: notifications

I bought some Xiaomi phones to play video games, and then set a notification so that when something happens in the game while I am on the computer, then the phone would play some audio and also vibrate.

However, it is strange that some phone would do both. Some only vibrate, and some do not do either, but just slide down a narrow dialog at the top of the screen for a few seconds. It is even the case that a phone that played audio would stop playing audio a few days later, with nothing changed for the notification settings.

Is there a way to make them all work reliably?

I was thinking of the Do Not Disturb but the notifications are set to "give notification even in Do Not Disturb mode", so this should not be the reason.

Comment: Based on the notification you can use [automation](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/automation/info) to trigger playing audio and vibrate

Comment: [Example](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/133209/131553)