# Is there a way to enable the ringer/notification sounds only when using headphones?

Tags: notifications, ringtone, headphones

Let me explain the scenario:

I **always** keep my phone in vibration mode (no ringer, no notification sounds, just the vibration), since I'm a forgetful person and I'd end up forgetting to turn the ringer off when I'm in a meeting or other occasions when it wouldn't be appropriate.

This works fine for my needs, except in one instance: when listening to music. When I listen to music I typically keep my phone in the pocket of my jacket and I end up missing all my notifications, since between the music and the fact I don't have the phone in my hand or on my desk I can't hear nor feel the vibration.

My question is: is there a way to turn the ringer/notification sound on when the headphones are connected, while keeping it off when they aren't?

I'm running rooted stock Marshmallow (6.0.1)

Comment: Just for the sake of completeness, what is your phone model? Nexus phones (or *probably*, AOSP ROM and some other phones) have separate volume settings when on normal mode/headphone plugged.

Comment: @AndrewT. I'm on a Nexus 4 (AOSP). But the separate settings you mentioned only apply to media volume and (maybe) bluetooth. I tested it and the ringer/notification volume stays the same, with ot without headphones plugged.

Comment: Deleted my answer, as the SoundAbout app was actually doing something else (rerouting all audio to headphones) than what I thought it was doing (unmuting on headphone insert).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't have Android Marshmallow but following apps can easily achieve the goal on Android Lollipop 5.1. Should not fail on your OS, I believe. Let me know the result in any case.

## [MacroDroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.arlosoft.macrodroid)

**When headphones are plugged:**

- Trigger: Headphones Insert/Remove → Headphones Inserted
- Action: Volume Change → select Notification and Ringer, and configure the slider for the level of volume you want

**When headphones are removed:**

- Trigger: Headphones Insert/Remove → Headphones Removed
- Action: Volume Change → select Notification and Ringer, and keep the slider to 0

## [Automate](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.llamalab.automate)

It seems to work too. Your flow should look like this:

<sub>(Click image to enlarge)</sub>

[image: IMG:]

Relevant blocks:

- Interface → Wired headset plugged?
- Settings → Ringer mode set

The said flow would cause the ringer and notification volume to come back to the level you set them to, before switching the phone to vibration.

## [Atooma](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.atooma)

It worked as well. However, it appears to not been updated since May 2015.

**When headphones are connected:**

- IF: Headphone → Plugged
- DO: Audio Manager → Set ringer volume → configure the slider
- DO: Audio Manager → Notification volume → configure the slider

**When headphones are removed:**

- IF: Headphone → Unplugged
- DO: Silent mode → On → Vibrate: Yes

## [Droid Automation](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.wakdev.droidautomation.free)

It also worked well for me.

Instructions:

1. Profile: Headset plugged

   1. Trigger: Headset state → Becomes plugged
   2. Task: Sounds & Media → Volume: Ringtones → configure
   3. Task: Sounds & Media → Volume: Notifications → configure
2. Profile: Headset unplugged

   1. Trigger: Headset state → Becomes unplugged
   2. Task: Sounds & Media → Volume: Ringtones → configure to zero

Comment: Ah, yes, doze mode. Thanks to LJD200 for mentioning it in their answer. In case MacroDroid fails because of Doze mode, try this answer as a remedy: [Is there a way to exclude an app from Doze?](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/129075)

Comment: Other settings *may* affect if not implemented, not just doze. Suggesting OP to have a look at this answer for all settings and a quick start guide to MacroDroid, if you don't mind http://android.stackexchange.com/a/133394/131553

Comment: The only settings/issues that are relevant here from your answer are about task killers and the running Android's special battery optimization techniques. Accessibility and notification access settings has nothing to do with the triggers I proposed. But thanks. *I would recommend OP* to specifically look for the heading *System Settings* in your linked answer, if not concerned with quick guide since app already offers that. :)

Comment: Used MacroDroid, seems to work well. As for doze: doesn't plugging/unplugging the headphones actually generate an event that wakes up the device anyway? (not sure about this, just asking)

Comment: @Master_T, sorry, I can't really comment on how doze handles these things. A simple logic follows that plugging headset results in a broadcast `android.intent.action.HEADSET_PLUG` being issued. MacroDroid would've registered a receiver for that broadcast so that it can be notified immediately and the actions get executed per user's  configuration. What I don't know is whether Android, when doze is active, allows apps to be activated for such inconsequential broadcast.

Answer (score 2):

Ensure [Tasker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm) is installed and enabled. I tested this with Tasker 4.8 on Android 6.0.1 Marshmallow. If you are using Tasker on Marshmallow, it will work more effectively if you disable battery optimisation under the Android Settings (although this may also drain the battery quicker). To do this, navigate to `Battery` -> `Triple dot menu` (in the upper-right hand corner) -> `Battery optimisation`. Then click on the drop-down menu and select `All apps` and scroll down to `Tasker`. Click on `Tasker` and press `Don't optimise` followed by `Done`.

To do this, open Tasker and create a new task. Name it whatever you like. Then add an action and navigate to `Audio` -> `Ringer Volume`. Drag the slider to 7 (this is the maximum volume and you can adjust this if you want). Do the same for `Audio` -> `Notifcation Volume` under the same task.

Now add a profile and navigate to `State` -> `Hardware` -> `Headset Plugged`. Don't change the default options here and navigate back. You will now be prompted to add a task. Select the task that you created earlier.

Once ensuring that the profile is enabled, exit Tasker and set your notifcation/ringer volume to vibrate.

That's it. The ringer and notification volumes should now change automatically when you plug and unplug your headphones.