# Multiple notifications arrive all at once, from multiple apps

Tags: notifications, 6.0-marshmallow, 7.0-nougat

I'm using an LG Nexus 5X (android 7.0, also did the same on Marshmallow), and over the last few weeks I've noticed that sometimes a load of notifications will come in at once(within seconds), say 3, 5, 10. Some quite old (hours).
eg 5x facebook, 3x email at once. A couple of weeks ago I had 20+ twitter notifications pour in in a couple of seconds.

This doesn't happen all the time, sometimes after I move or wake the phone, so makes me think its suspending notifications based on motion, if that's a thing?!

It also doesn't appear to be any different on wifi vs 4G, I have no issues with browsing or calling.

Answer (score 2):

Going by your description of not happening when you " move or shake the phone" , it appears to be related to *[Doze](https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby.html)* function of Android, which may be the cause

You would need to exclude these apps from the Doze feature. I am not sure how to do that on Nougat but on Marshmallow,   [Is there a way to exclude an app from Doze?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/129074/131553)  should help you exclude those apps ( steps to exclude would probably be similar on Nougat )

**Edit:** Doze behaviour has been [changed](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/nougat/android-7.0-changes.html) in Nougat. Doze is implemented in two stages

> When a device is on battery power, and the screen has been off for a certain time, the device enters Doze and applies the *first* subset of restrictions: It shuts off app network access, and defers jobs and syncs. If the device is stationary for a certain time after entering Doze, the system applies the *rest of the Doze restrictions* to PowerManager.WakeLock, AlarmManager alarms, GPS, and Wi-Fi scans.

My understanding is that this change does not help your problem , without excluding from Doze

Comment: Ah excellent thank you! I'll have a play and report back...

Comment: I have excluded several apps from Battery Optimisation (Doze mode) So far its looking good, but want to give it a few days before marking this as the answer, just to be sure.