# All notifications come at the same time

Tags: push-notifications

I have a Samsung S21 Ultra 5G, using Android OS 11
I have enabled push notifications for multiple apps and gave them all different notification sounds.

Apps like news, twitter, banking, online ordering, transport alerts, weather report etc.

Periodically they all arrive at the same time causing a cacophony of notification sounds which is quite annoying.

I'd like to have the notifications as they're pushed from the apps server (as they happen), rather then having them in groups causing a notification overload.

I'm not sure if this has something to do with the Wi-Fi setting ("Wifi Power Save Mode" is set to OFF) or network syncing period.

How can I set my phone so that important and specific apps deliver their notifications as they happen, rather than being grouped with others?
For example I'd like to be notified when a person who I follow on twitter and have their notifications turned on as soon as they tweet, rather than being notified in 10 minutes or in an hour. Same with my news alerts etc...

I'm not sure if this was always the case with my phone and became obvious as I enabled more and more app notifications.

I thank everybody in advance who are willing to reply to help.

I have seen this post but it's really old and our problems are not quite the same;
[Multiple notifications arrive all at once, from multiple apps](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/155808/multiple-notifications-arrive-all-at-once-from-multiple-apps)

Comment: That all notifications are grouped together is by design to save battery. Also usually all notifications are received by PlayServices app and then distributed to the apps.

Comment: Ty for your response.
I was wondering if there's anything I can do, or a setting that I can change to ungroup  and recieve them as they are pushed, waivering from battery power? Or perhaps decrease the time in between PlayServices distributes them?