# How to schedule downloads in Advance Download manager?

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, downloading, download-manager

I installed Advanced Download manager to schedule my downloading for night time. I know how to schedule and it works as long as the app is open. So I put some files for downloading and schedule it for a late night download. But the app closes by itself after sometimes, resulting failure in downloading the intended files. How can a tweak it so that I can schedule my downloads for the desired period?

thanks.

Comment: Device and OS details please ? Is it rooted?

Comment: Xiaomi redmi 3s prime with Marshmellow, MIUI 8. Nor rooted.@beeshyams

Comment: Did you check Doze settings and verify that the app is not optimised? see http://android.stackexchange.com/q/129074/131553

Answer (score 1):

For you to download on schedule, ADM requires a running service program. Make sure you do not close the service after you have enabled your scheduler
You can do this by:

- Giving ADM a higher memory priority (so that it will not be killed when system memory is low)
- Whitelisting ADM in phone's power saving features, task killers or hibenation programs
- Enabling a persistent notification to keep the program's services running in the background.