# How to make Android app always run in background in Huawei Honor 6X?

Tags: downloading, background-process, huawei-honor-6

I am having Huawei Honor 6X in which if I open any app and minimize it, after 1 minute it automatically closes. For example, I want to download using [ADM (Advance Download Manager)](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.dv.adm) where I plan download to automatically start at night, but as soon as I minimize it, it closes.

How to fix this?

Comment: Try disabling ADM from *screen lock cleanup or protected apps* battery saving feature . I don't have device so I don't know which battery saving feature you have

Answer (score 0):

For you to download on schedule, ADM requires a running service program. Make sure you do not close the service after you have enabled your scheduler.

You can do this by:

- Giving ADM a higher memory priority (so that it will not be killed when system memory is low)
- Whitelisting ADM in phone's power saving features, task killers or hibernation programs
- Enabling a persistent notification to keep the program's services running in the background. (Settings >> Notification Manager >> Always allow) See screenshot:

[image: ADM persistent notification]

See: [How to schedule downloads in Advance Download manager](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/170737/how-to-schedule-downloads-in-advance-download-manager/170757#170757), and check if it works

Also keep it running in background through phone manager:

[image: ADM keeps running in background]

I had a similar issue with other apps automatically closing but this solved may problems. Hope it helps.