# Clearing the notification about battery issues

Tags: notifications, battery, background-process

My android doesn't understand why I carry my phone. It thinks that if Outlook and Skype are running all the time (so I can get push notifications) that it's a waste of my battery, and the thing to do is shut those down so that I can get more than 24 hour battery life. Thing is, with those shut down, carrying the phone is pointless.

Today it sprouted a notification on the Settings icon:

[image: screenshot]

When I go in there, it wants to "fix" my "issues" by shutting down Outlook whenever I am not looking at it:

[image: screenshot]

I don't consider this to be a drain. (It claims elsewhere Outlook is using 1% of my battery and that at this rate it will only last another 24 hours. That's fine by me.) **I don't want this "fixed"**. I want Outlook and Skype to run all the time so I can get notified immediately if someone is trying to contact me. I want to clear that orange notification from my Settings tile. Yet none of this seems to be possible. Apparently the only option I have is to agree to have my phone turn off all the things I use it for, for my own good.

How can I get what I want?

This is a Samsung Galaxy S7 running Android 7.0.

Comment: Please update your question with your device make, model, and Android version... That information is necessary to formulate a concise answer.

Comment: @acejavelin done

Comment: If it's essential to you to have those apps running 24/7, why not excluding them from "battery optimization" (Doze mode)? If you don't know how to do that, please take a look at [Is there a way to exclude an app from Doze?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/129074/16575)

Comment: May I ask whether you have any battery saving or cleaner app installed?

Comment: I do not. I have very little installed and nothing "meta" like that.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the comment by Izzy above, I looked further under the Battery settings. There is nothing about Doze, but there is a section called Unmonitored Apps which apparently means "unrestricted" apps. I was able to add Outlook (but not Skype) to this list. The phone now says it will let them use all the power they want. Good.

Doing so has cleared the orange dot, which is great, and should also mean that I will get my push notifications. I guess. I don't really understand how Android works and seem to be constantly trying to stop it helping me.